# Instagram URL is converted into oEmbed

Tags: shortcode, embed, oembed, block-editor

I have 8 Instagram URLs in this [post](https://blog.wwf.sg/ocean/2018/11/netflix-documentaries-our-planet-okja-dogs/) out of which 3 are not converted into embed/iframes.

I'm using Gutenberg's Instagram embed blog to add the URL's.https://blog.wwf.sg/ocean/2018/11/netflix-documentaries-our-planet-okja-dogs/#

I see the block code in the classic editor which is same as other instagram blocks which render properly but for https://www.instagram.com/p/BqDzw0CF3pC/ it just returns URL.

```
<!-- wp:core-embed/instagram {"url":"https://www.instagram.com/p/BqDzw0CF3pC/","type":"rich","providerNameSlug":"instagram","className":""} -->
<figure class="wp-block-embed-instagram wp-block-embed is-type-rich is-provider-instagram">
  <div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
    https://www.instagram.com/p/BqDzw0CF3pC/
</div>
</figure>
<!-- /wp:core-embed/instagram -->
```

I tried using shortcode also it's the same result only the below 3 Instagram posts don't render.

`[embed]https://www.instagram.com/p/BqDzw0CF3pC/[/embed]`

I need help debugging this weired issue

- http://www.instagram.com/p/BMY9o6yA6m1
- http://www.instagram.com/p/BeqpirDAbol
- https://www.instagram.com/p/BqDzw0CF3pC/

Comment: Looks like a bug. I'd add a bug report to WP Trac...

Comment: I tested it in different a different wordpress instance. It works seamlessly.

Comment: Any conflicts with other plugins/theme?

Comment: Disabled all plugins and tested with 2017 theme. The issue still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

Embed shortcode stores the oemebd data as post meta using md5 hash.

[wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/91da29d9afaa664eb84e1261ebb916b18a362aa9/wp-includes/class-wp-embed.php#L198)

```php
// Check for a cached result (stored in the post meta)
$key_suffix = md5( $url . serialize( $attr ) );
$cachekey = '_oembed_' . $key_suffix;
$cachekey_time = '_oembed_time_' . $key_suffix;
```

And has a cache mechanism to fetch new data only after a day.

I deleted the post meta and then it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me the solution was to add this code to  theme.

```
if ( !isset( $content_width ) ) $content_width = 550;
```

More info https://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-oembed/

Hope it helps someone.